# Unable to find module qiskit_aqua.algorithms

Tags: python, quantum-computing, qiskit

```
pip-install qiskit-aqua completed successfully.
```

Following is ths stack trace:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-8f03022943b2> in <module>()
      2 import sys
      3 from datasets import *
----> 4 from qiskit_aqua.algorithms.many_sample.qsvm.data_preprocess import *
      5 from qiskit_aqua.input import get_input_instance
      6 from qiskit_aqua import run_algorithm
```

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qiskit_aqua.algorithms'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some searching, I found the code that you're running: it appears to come from one of the tutorials in the repository at https://github.com/Qiskit/aqua-tutorials. The current version of this repository is compatible with the current master branch of the Qiskit Aqua repository at https://github.com/Qiskit/aqua, which is currently somewhat ahead of the latest version available on PyPI (i.e. the one you installed using PIP). I expect PyPI will be updated with the latest version soon, but in the meantime I'd recommend that you clone the master branch of the Qiskit Aqua repository from GitHub. You can then install it using pip install -e if desired.